# How to use Git to track user's dotfiles?

Tags: git, dotfiles

As many people do, I have my [dotfiles](/questions/tagged/dotfiles) on GitHub. Having a `.git` repository on my `home` directory causes me some trouble sometime.

1. `git status` shows me plenty of untracked files.

I can partially solve this by writing a `.gitignore` that ignore everything that is not a *dotfile*:

```
#.gitignore
!.*
.viminfo
.cache
# ...
```

2. Everything inside my home directory becomes part of my Git repository

If I create a new directory `mkdir foo && cd foo` and forget to do `git init` I will be using my home Git repository instead of the new repository I was supposed to create. So I want to avoid this problem by limiting Git to some folders only.

As I don't usually `push`/`pull` my dotfiles, I came across this tick in which I simply rename my home Git repository when I don't use it:

```
alias githide='mv .git .git_hidden'
alias gitshow='mv .git_hidden .git'
```

Is there a better alternative against these issues?

Comment: "Better" is a matter of opinion, but I use symlinks, e.g., my `~/.gitconfig` is a symlink to `Dotfiles/gitconfig` (I drop the leading `.` in the repository version).  The obvious drawback is remembering to make the symlink.  A less obvious one is that some programs are wary of symlinks (so far I have not had issues, ssh is one that checks for symlinks within `.ssh` but `.ssh` itself can be a symlink).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use symlinks to those dotfiles and keep them in a separate folder.

```
$ cd ~
$ ln -s myDotfilesRepo/.gitconfig
```

If you want to be a bit more advanced you could use GNU Stow to handle dotfiles.

Let's say your dotfiles repo has the following structure:

```
.
├── git
│   ├── .gitconfig
│   └── .gitignore
```

Then you could install the whole git package using stow in the following way.

```
cd ~
git clone git@github.com:user/dotfiles.git
cd dotfiles
stow git
```

The result is that both files have been symlinked

```
ls -la ~/.git*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user     27 aug.  13 10:17 .gitconfig -> dotfiles/git/.gitconfig
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user     27 aug.  13 10:17 .gitignore -> dotfiles/git/.gitignore
```

Comment: I do the same thing. Making your home directory a git repository is a bit of a headache since there will be other repos inside it etc.

Answer (score 0):

A Git repository is usually present in the `.git` folder, itself placed with the files being tracked by this repository.

The `.git` folder is the Git repository, everything else is called the work tree.

But the work tree doesn't have to be next to the Git repository, it can be anywhere else on the file system.

So it is possible to use a Git repository with its work tree being your home folder, without causing any interference with other repositories inside your home folder.

Here are the steps to make this:

- Create a bare repository (which is a repository without work tree, so it contains only what is usually in the `.git` folder):

```bash
git init --bare ~/my-config
```

- Configure the work tree of the repository (effectively making it not bare anymore) to be your home folder:

```bash
cd ~/my-config
git config --unset core.bare
git config core.worktree /home/<your-name>
```

- Configure Git to not show untracked files, so commands like `git status` will not show thousands of files:

```bash
git config status.showUntrackedFiles no
```

- If you use some GUI programs, like Sublime Merge, you might want to add a `.gitignore` file as well, because `status.showUntrackedFiles` might be ignored by these programs:

```bash
echo "*" > ~/.gitignore
```

And that's it! Now you can begin to track dotfiles in your home folder with:

```bash
git add ~/path/to/your/.file # ← Add flag `-f` if you have made the `.gitignore`
```

You can make some aliases or functions in your `.zshrc` (or equivalent):

```bash
# I use functions instead of aliases to have folder and file name completion
config-add() {
    git --git-dir="$HOME/my-config" add -f $@
}
config-untrack() {
    git --git-dir="$HOME/my-config" rm --cached $@
}
```

So you can add one or more files to your dotfiles repo from anywhere with:

```bash
config-add path/to/file1 path/to/file2
```

One warning: be very careful with other git commands! Commands like `git clean` could delete every untracked files from your home directory! This means everything except your dotfiles.